# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError with Ngrx

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I know this may be encountered several times but I can't find a clean efficient way to solve it.
I have a piece of code like this
`<div *ngIf="userUsername$ | async as username"></div>` and when I run I get this

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: [object Object]'. Current value: 'ngIf: admin'.

in my component.ts
`userUsername$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectSelectedUsername));`

Is there any efficient way to fix this rather than `setTimeout`?

Thank you,

**UPDATE**

entire component's code as requested

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { select, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { selectSelectedUsername } from '../state-management/selectors/user.selector';
import { IAppState } from '../state-management/state/app.state';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-layout',
  templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layout.component.sass']
})
export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  userUsername$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectSelectedUsername));

  constructor(
    private store: Store<IAppState>
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  ngOnDestroy() { }

}
```

Comment: Can you show your entire component?

Comment: Don’t try to hack your way out of the error with things like setTimeout or even ChangeDetectorRef until you understand the error and unidirectional data flow.

Comment: @MikeOne as per your request, I updated my question with the entire code, it doesn't do anything rather than registering to the store, thank u

Comment: @MikeOne , the main issue i believe is that I dispatch the action from a child component, but I don't know any other place I should dispatch it from

Comment: @AndrewAllen please refer to my above comment

Comment: @JosephKhella I'd restructure. Proposed: LayoutComponent to accepts @Input() and knows nothing about the store. Parent / container takes care of fetching state and passing data to LayoutComponent. Child dispatching an action that affects parent bound values is cause of error as you have guessed.

Comment: @AndrewAllen I just used ngrx exactly not to use input and outputs to bind values, unless it's a representational component (and layout is not), I can use observables for this specific case, but still don't feel like it's the best sol

Comment: @AndrewAllen the only thing I can think of now is that I can make 2 more actions login/logoff and dispatch them from authentication modules and subscribe to them on the layout component

Comment: @JosephKhella I can't advice without knowing wider structure; where does `<div *ngIf="userUsername$ | async as username"></div>` appear compared to `<my-layout></my-layout>`; parent / child component chain; purpose of components in chain; router info for page getting error.

Comment: This is actually an interesting case...I have a similar case where I have a breadcrumb component on a very high level (lets say app.component) and modules / children that eventually get data (also from ngrx) and need to set the breadcrumb data from a (deeply) nested component. There I have the same issue. This is expected as the change detection tree is always downward so the breadcrumb was already checked once the child component is trying to change it. I need to think some more about this...

Comment: @MikeOne just for the record,  I changed my structure and the place i dispatch the action from and it worked, though I still can't find a solution for the main issue

Comment: @JosephKhella What did you change it to that made it work?

Comment: Also running into a similar issue. In my case, I am mapping the store value into a boolean value and using in html template using an async pipe. The initial store value is undefined. If I console.log the value, I see the default undefined value, and immediately after, the value that has been set. The value is dispatched from an effect after an http get request. This warning could be a common case with ngrx? For my situation, I just rxjs `filter` the undefined value. Or another is using rxjs `debounceTime(0)`. That said, not sure if this is the "right" way

Answer (score -1):

**if you want to solve this error so you can use this**

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

  constructor(
    title: Title,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){ }


 this.cdr.detectChanges();
```

**Note:****After your variable value changed to use this line**

```
this.cdr.detectChanges();
```